# JavaScript functions not working together to display image

Tags: javascript, html, css, function

I am trying to get user input and then print that number of boxes on the screen, I can get the boxes spawning if I do no checks and just set them to spawn whenever I click one, However, once I start adding in checks the boxes just stop spawning.

```js
var count = 1;

function spawnBox() {
  var container = document.getElementById("container");
  var newBox = document.createElement("div");
  newBox.className = "box";
  newBox.innerHTML = count;
  container.appendChild(newBox);
  count++
}

function checkIfCanSpawn() {
  while (count < inputNumber) {
    spawnBox();
  }
}
```

```css
div.box {
  width: 10vw;
  height: 8vw;
  background: rgb(8, 144, 168);
  margin: 1vw;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 5vw;
  padding-top: 1vw;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<label id="type in a number" name="Input a number"> Type In a number </label>
<input id="inputNum" type="number" name="inputNumber"> </input>
```

Comment: `inputNumber` is just the name of the input element. You've to read the value of the input.

Comment: Also, your `checkIfCanSpawn` function is missing a closing bracket.

Comment: you try get an element with the id "container" but there is no such element.

Comment: And you have spaces in your label id, which is not allowed.

Comment: Where do you call `checkIfCanSpawn()` from? Where is `inputnumber` defined?

Comment: Indeed, my mistake

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hp84cxwm/1/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I am trying to define ```inputnumber``` to be the value of whatever int the person types in so all i am using is ```inputNumber.value``` i now call checkIfCanSpawn during an ```onclick``` when the input is clicked

Comment: But you're using `inputnumber`, not `inputnumber.value`. Can you edit the code in the question to show a complete example?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i just added ```.value``` the end of that ```inputnumber```, i didnt realise at first i needed to have ```.value``` afterwards to get the actual value.

Comment: Hi [Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10430558/matt),
aren't you satisfied with my proposed solution with the button?
How about [smough](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1657931/smough)' answer ?

Answer (score 1):

Tweaked a little to make it work.

Added onchange event on input class.
then instead of using the count, i made use of the available while loop and passed the count instead.
then clear the "container" every run.

```js
function spawnBox(count) {
  // Get the container
  var container = document.getElementById("container");

  // Create a new div
  var newBox = document.createElement("div");
  newBox.className = "box";
  newBox.innerHTML = count;

  // Append it to the container
  container.appendChild(newBox);

  // Increment count
  count++
}

function checkIfCanSpawn() {

  document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = "";
  var inputNumber = document.getElementById("inputNum").value;
  var x = 1;
  while (x <= inputNumber) {
    spawnBox(x);
    x++;
  }
}
```

```css
div.box {
  width: 10vw;
  height: 8vw;
  background: rgb(8, 144, 168);
  margin: 1vw;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 5vw;
  padding-top: 1vw;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<label id="type in a number" name="Input a number"> Type In a number </label>
<input id="inputNum" type="number" name="inputNumber" onchange="checkIfCanSpawn()" />

<div id="container"></div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lqj4dktw/

Answer (score 0):

Add a button with a click-eventHandler to call the spawnBox():

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
  $("#btn" ).click(function(){
    let inputNumber = $("#inputNum").val();
      while (count < inputNumber) {
          spawnBox();
      }
  })
})
```

Her is a [working fiddle](https://codepen.io/meziano/pen/OJVpKEQ)